# How to implement rolling mean ignoring null values

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I am trying calculate RSI indicator. For that I need rolling-mean gain and loss.

I would like to calculate rolling mean ignoring null values. So mean would be calculated by sum and count on existing values.

Example:

```
window_size = 5

df = DataFrame(price_change: { 1, 2, 3, -2, 4 })

df_gain = .select(
            pl.when(pl.col('price_change') > 0.0)
            .then(pl.col('price_change'))
            .otherwise(None)
            .alias('gain')
          )

# UNKOWN HOW TO GET WANTED RESULT:
rol_mean_gain = df_gain.select(
                  pl.col('gain').rolling_mean(window_size=window_size, ignore_null=True)
                )
```

So that rol_mean_gain be calculated: `[1, 2, 3, skip, 4] / 4 (not 5)`

I know Pandas has `.mean(skipna=True)` or `.apply(pandas.np.nanmean)`
But as far as I am aware polars does not provide such API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the skipping of nulls is implied, see the `min_periods` description in the [docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_mean.html#polars.Expr.rolling_mean) for this method.

```
df_gain.select(pl.col('gain').rolling_mean(window_size=window_size, min_periods=1))
```

Gives me a column of `1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.0, 2.5`. Note how the last two columns skips the null correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Got the most accurate results using `min_periods=0`